# varchar with length from a stored variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to call a variable for the length of a field (`varchar`). Typically I always use `nvarchar(max)` for most things other than when I need a numeric field for math purposes. This is okay until the tables are big and performance takes a big hit.

Is it possible to create a column using `varchar(max)`, then run a length query to create the highest number of characters (this example is just one record, so I'm not truly filtering on a max value. I understand that). Then store that number into a variable and call that variable into creating a new varchar column?

Other uses would be maybe be storing that output/result as a variable for other statements.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    MyCol nvarchar(max) 
);

INSERT INTO Test (MyCol)
VALUES ('asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfsasdfadfs');

SELECT LEN(MyCol) FROM Test

--44 characters. Store this as output as variable

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD NewMyCol varchar(VARIABLE_HERE?) --LEN from above

UPDATE TEST SET NewMyCol = MyCol FROM test
```

Comment: You can't parameterize that, no. (`Msg 112, Variables are not allowed in the ALTER TABLE statement`). You'd need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: *I always use nvarchar(max) for most things* this is *not* good practice!

Comment: Why not just design your database properly selecting lengths that match the business requirements? SQL is by design a static language/structure. Its not intended to be dynamic/fluid.

Comment: Know your data and leave a little extra room for growth if applicable.

Comment: The fact you're even asking this sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) (I've never needed this in 20+ years) and researching into how SQL Server builds an execution plan would help understand why you cannot parameterise like you expect. (or even just reading the documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments are accurate, it seems quite dangerous to me to add a column based on the *current* length stored in the table, and I don't really see the benefit.

However, since people will want to do it regardless of how many people pile on saying it's a bad idea:

```
DECLARE @len int;
SELECT @len = MAX(LEN(MyCol)) FROM dbo.Test;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD NewMyCol varchar($l$);';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, N'$l$', RTRIM(@len));
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PxQssL3X).